# How do you solve Thevenin equivalent for circuits with variable resistors?

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

I have this circuit and I have to solve the Thevenin equivalent across the terminals A and B. How do I solve for R<sub>Th</sub> in terms of the variables present in the circuit?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not to have one (or two) variable resistors, because you always take a look at one moment and treat them as fixed during your analysis.

I guess your problem is to see that the variable resistor (potentiometer) actually consists of **two** resistors (R2 and R - R2). In general they form a  voltage divider; in this particular case one of the two "sub"-resistors (R - R2) is shorted so you can forget the (R - R2) part (i.e. treat it as being 0).